# iOS Swift UITableView Auto Cell Scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6.3

I need a bit of help. I am new and still learning. But I was wondering if anyone has a bit of an idea of how to get the text that is going off the screen in the cell to get it so that it will auto scroll?

[image]

Comment: Many controls exist to accomplish this. You can subclass the cell and use a Marquee Label instead of a standard UILabel. Here's a control: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it later on tonight.